# Ruby Programming: 'gets' execution expired Timeout.timeout error

Tags: ruby, timeout

I have constructed a very simple `Ruby` program whilst exploring the `Timeout`module, using [this site as a guide](https://flushentitypacket.github.io/ruby/2015/02/21/ruby-timeout-how-does-it-even-work.html).

```
print "\nEnter Input:"

require 'timeout'
Timeout::timeout(5) do
    input = gets.chomp
end

print "\nEXITING\n"
```

When I run the script, it prompts the user for input, however after 5 seconds, instead of simply printing "EXITING" and promptly terminating as it logically should, it instead crashes, returning the error:

`'gets': execution expired (Timeout::Error)`

I am wondering why this is, and how this error could be avoided whilst the script waits for user input for 5 seconds before terminating regardless.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Please see the documentation for the Module [Timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html)

It clearly states that it *performs an operation in a block, raising an error if it takes longer than sec seconds to complete*.

To get your desired output, you can use a `rescue` block to rescue the `Timeout::Error` and then show your `EXITING` message:

```
require 'timeout'

print "\nEnter Input:"
begin
  Timeout::timeout(5) do
    input = gets.chomp
  end
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  print "\nEXITING\n"
end
```

Comment: Exactly! "Help, my code is doing exactly what it's supposed to do!" This is why reading the manual's always important.